# Payload Too Large - says in console from dropzone.js when try to upload file larger than 10MB

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am using dropzone for uploading file with following settings.

```
$("#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone({ // The camelized version of the ID of the form element
        previewTemplate: document
            .querySelector('#tpl')
            .innerHTML,
        // The configuration we've talked about above
        url: '{!! route('pam.submissions.store', $stage->id) !!}',
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 100,
        maxFiles: 100,
        maxFilesize:200,//MB
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        timeout: 120000,

        // The setting up of the dropzone
        init: function() {
        //init code
        },

    });
```

Even after setting the value of "maxFilesize" to 200 (which means 200 MB), I can not upload file larger than 10MB. When try to upload, there comes error in console that says "POST {SUBMISSION-URL} 413 (Payload Too Large)". I was wondering what is the reason behind it. Is there anything wrong done by me ? How to fix this ?

Comment: That's a server side error code, check your server settings.

Comment: It's answer from server, it's not about dropzone. Client is trying to send the file, backend tells that it's too large to be accepted. See your backend config.

Answer (score 0):

it was my problem too and i fixed by increasing post max size in php.ini